# R Markdown (Flexdashboard) Mobile Format

Tags: css, r, mobile, markdown, flexdashboard

I have an R Markdown report (flexdashboard) which works perfectly well when opened on desktops. It is exported to an HTML and shipped this way via an uploaded link.

However, the formatting simply does not work nicely on mobile (it's all squeezed), especially since my report has multiple complex fillRow/fillCol from shiny, which formats it precisely to specifications.

I'm looking for a solution where, if the user is viewing the HTML on mobile, it either automatically:

1. Option One: Reformats it completely so that I've just got all the blocks one after the other - or some other palatable layout that I can specify (which would need to be different from the original markdown code which specifies how to layout the boxes via fillRow/fillCol for wider screens)

   OR
2. Option Two: On mobiles, it does NOT reformat anything whatsoever, but fits the entire report to the screen. The user views the report as they might sort of when opening a PDF export of the file on their phone, where they just zoom in and out as needed.

Forgive me in advance if there is an obvious answer, as I'm a bit new and my understanding of this is limited to R and a bit of CSS.

````
---
title: "Test"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: rows
    vertical_layout: scroll
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)
library(shiny)
```

Row {data-height=250}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Chart A

```{r}
head(mtcars)

```

Row {data-height=40}
-------------------------------------
<br/>
<span style="color:#007dbc;font-size:14px">&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;In Numbers</span> 


Row {data-height=100}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
### Beneficiaries reached so far
```{r}
# Manual number reached
valueBox("111", icon = "ion-ionic", color="#007dbc")
```

### Beneficiaries reached so far
```{r}
# Manual number reached
valueBox("111", icon = "ion-ionic", color="#007dbc")
```



Row {data-height=350}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Chart B

```{r}
fillRow(
  plot_ly(
    data = mtcars,
    x = ~mpg,
    y = ~cyl),
  plot_ly(
    data = mtcars,
    x = ~disp,
    y = ~drat)
  )
```

### Chart C
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
````

My original **styles.css** sheet also includes the following which kept it at a precise width, but it doesn't seem to apply for mobiles.

```
body {
    color: #000000;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    min-width: 1100px;
    max-width: 1100px;
    border-right: 1px solid;
    border-right-color: #e4e4e4;
}
```

Comment: have you seen [Rshiny mobile](https://rinterface.github.io/shinyMobile/)? it's a package made by a group called *rinterface*... but this might require some changing of your flexdashboard to play into the framework, don't you need `runtime: shiny` in your YAML header?

Comment: Hi @DanielJachetta, thanks for this; however my code is basic markdown without a server to run it on and I just export it to HTML.